# Match Multiple Strings and return the results in R

Tags: r

I have a question regarding to functionality like to find and match multiple strings in R.

I have 3 tables below.

Table 1: with Jurisdiction, product code and rates, Product code can be split into two components, primary being the first 3 product code and the last two as secondary code e.g. AB010, AB020, AB030 are primary code and AB040, AB050 are secondary key.

Table 2: with juridiction and product name, product name will consist of a lot of non-sense string in between the Primary and secondary code, but it will always contain only one primary code and may or may not contain a secondary code and are splited by "_",

Table 3: Output Table, I want to search and return the product code from Product name in Table 2 and match the Rate in Table1, e.g.
if product name contains both AB010 and AB040, it will be 1.1+1.4 = 2.5.

I am currently using a lot of nested ifelse function in R.

```
Jurisdiction <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")

Product.Code <- c("AB010","AB020","AB030","AB040","AB050","X120","X130","X140","X150","X160","ZH123","ZH124","ZH125","ZH130","ZH131")

Rates <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5)

Table1 <- data.frame(Jurisdiction, Product.Code, Rates)

Jurisdiction_2<- c("A","A","C","B")

Product.name <- c("1234_AB010_dsf","1234_AB010_AB040_tsdfl","1238_ZH123_ZH131","123_X140")

Table2 <- data.frame(Jurisdiction_2, Product.name)



Table 1     
Jurisdiction    Product Code    Rates
A   AB010   1.1
A   AB020   1.2
A   AB030   1.3
A   AB040   1.4
A   AB050   1.5
B   X120    1.1
B   X130    1.2
B   X140    1.3
B   X150    1.4
B   X160    1.5
C   ZH123   1.1
C   ZH124   1.2
C   ZH125   1.3
C   ZH130   1.4
C   ZH131   1.5
Table 2 
Jurisdiction_2    Product.name
A   1234_AB010_dsf
A   1234_AB010_AB040_tsdfl
C   1238_ZH123_ZH131
B   123_X140
Table 3         
Jurisdiction    Product name    Product Code    Rate
A   1234_AB010  AB010   1.1
A   1234_AB010_AB040    AB010/AB040 2.5
C   1238_ZH123_ZH131    ZH123/ZH131 2.6
B   123_X140    X140    1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for the `fuzzyjoin` package; you can treat the codes in `Table1` as regular expressions and match them to the longer strings in `Table2`.  Try something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

table3 = Table2 %>%
  regex_left_join(Table1 %>%
                    mutate(product.regex = paste("(_|^)", Product.Code, "(_|$)", sep = ""),
                           jurisdiction.regex = paste("^", Jurisdiction, "$", sep = "")),
                  by = c("Product.name" = "product.regex",
                         "Jurisdiction_2" = "jurisdiction.regex")) %>%
  group_by(Jurisdiction_2, Product.name) %>%
  summarize(Product.Codes = toString(Product.Code),
            Rate = sum(Rates))
```

A couple of points:

- I wrapped `Product.Code` from `Table1` in a longer regular expression to ensure that it's both preceded and followed in `Table2` by either `_` or the end of the string.  If you are certain that all product codes are exactly 5 characters (i.e., no product code is a substring of any other code), this isn't necessary.
- I wasn't sure whether you also need to join on jurisdiction.  I included jurisdiction in the join just in case, adding `^...$` to the regular expression to force the jurisdictions to match perfectly.  If you don't need to match on jurisdiction, you can omit that part.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, the product code length is between 5 characters to 10 characters so it is necessary, I will have a look at the exact coding and modify to test the functionality when I sit in front of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using `sapply`

```
Table3 <- as.data.frame(row.names = F,
  t(
    sapply(Table2$Product.name, function(pname) { # line 1
      qry.names <- paste0("^", gsub("_", "|^", pname)) # line 2
      pcodes <- grep(qry.names, Table1$Product.Code, perl = T) # line 3
      pcodes.c <- paste0(sort(unique(Table1$Product.Code[pcodes])), collapse = "/") # line 4
      Jurisdiction <- Table2$Jurisdiction_2[pname == Table2$Product.name] #line 5
      list(Jurisdiction, pname, pcodes.c, sum(Table1$Rates[pcodes])) # line 6
    })
  )
)

# set column names
colnames(Table3) <- c("Jurisdiction", "Product name", "Product Code", "Rate")

> Table3
  Jurisdiction           Product name Product Code Rate
1            A         1234_AB010_dsf        AB010  1.1
2            A 1234_AB010_AB040_tsdfl  AB010/AB040  2.5
3            C       1238_ZH123_ZH131  ZH123/ZH131  2.6
4            B               123_X140         X140  1.3
```

1. Apply `function(pname)` for each `Product.name` in `Table2`
2. Replace `_` with `|^` in the `Product.name` and append an additional `^` in front to use it as query for `grep` search in `Table1$Product.code`
3. Get the positions of `Product.Code` in `Table1` where `Table2$Product.name` matches
4. Paste corresponding `Table1$Product.Code`s separated by `/`
5. Get `Jurisdiction`
6. Export required values

Comment: Thanks, my goal is to get the Product code columns, once I can pair up all the product code, I can simply join them. I try to apply both of your methods using the actual data, but it appears the Output Product Code is a list of the Target Product Code e.g. for row 1, Product Code will be like 'AB010, AB010, AB010, AB010...', and if there is no Product Code to match (due to error or type in the system), it will be 'NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ...'.

Comment: @perry I am not sure if I follow you.  The “Product code” column output is exactly same as your example.  What should be different?

Comment: Hi, both of your codes can replicate the output smoothly, it's just when I try to modify the code for fit the actual data, it actually creates a list of the correct output e.g. instead of showing AB010 for the first row, it returns a list of multiple AB010s.
I have bypassed this, but there is another problem, in the real data, the secondary product code showing in the product name might not be the same as the secondary product e.g. AB040 could be CH1, AB050 could be CH2 in Jurisdiction 1, is there anyway to distinguish this.

Comment: I have fixed the code a bit which I think will help for the first part of the problem you are describing.  However, for the second part, I am not sure if that is possible because it is matching for the codes occurring in the names with the product codes in table1.  If they are different, how are they going to match?